# How to specify alignment of constants

Tags: rust, memory, computer-science, vulkan

I want to achieve something like this:

```rust
#[repr(align(4))]
const SPV_CODE: &[u8] = include_bytes!('my-shader.spv');
```

How do I ensure that the constant is aligned to a multiplier-of-four address?

---

EDIT: to be clear, I want the embedded bytes themselves to align to 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a specific struct containing only this slice (or an array, I don't know precisely what you need), then put the alignment constraint on the struct.

Since I don't know if you want to align the slice (i.e. the fat-pointer) or the included bytes it refers (points) to, please find below two solutions in order to express alignment constraints.

```rust
#[repr(align(64))]
struct SpvCodeSlice<'a>(&'a [u8]);

const SPV_CODE_SLICE: SpvCodeSlice =
    SpvCodeSlice(include_bytes!("my-shader.spv"));

fn show_slice_alignment() {
    let slice_struct_ptr = &SPV_CODE_SLICE as *const _;
    let slice_bytes_ptr = SPV_CODE_SLICE.0.as_ptr();
    println!("slice_struct_ptr: {:?}", slice_struct_ptr);
    println!("slice_bytes_ptr: {:?}", slice_bytes_ptr);
    let slice_struct_addr = slice_struct_ptr as usize;
    let slice_bytes_addr = slice_bytes_ptr as usize;
    println!("slice_struct_addr%64: {:?}", slice_struct_addr % 64); // zero every time
    println!("slice_bytes_addr%64: {:?}", slice_bytes_addr % 64); // not zero!
}

#[repr(align(64))]
struct SpvCodeArray<const N: usize>([u8; N]);

const BYTES_LEN: usize = include_bytes!("my-shader.spv").len();
const SPV_CODE_ARRAY: SpvCodeArray<BYTES_LEN> =
    SpvCodeArray(*include_bytes!("my-shader.spv"));

fn show_array_alignment() {
    let array_struct_ptr = &SPV_CODE_ARRAY as *const _;
    let array_bytes_ptr = SPV_CODE_ARRAY.0.as_ptr();
    println!("array_struct_ptr: {:?}", array_struct_ptr);
    println!("array_bytes_ptr: {:?}", array_bytes_ptr);
    let array_struct_addr = array_struct_ptr as usize;
    let array_bytes_addr = array_bytes_ptr as usize;
    println!("array_struct_addr%64: {:?}", array_struct_addr % 64); // zero every time
    println!("array_bytes_addr%64: {:?}", array_bytes_addr % 64); // zero every time
}

fn main() {
    show_slice_alignment();
    println!("~~~~");
    show_array_alignment()
}
/*
slice_struct_ptr: 0x55e10101d1c0
slice_bytes_ptr: 0x55e10100f05b
slice_struct_addr%64: 0
slice_bytes_addr%64: 27
~~~~
array_struct_ptr: 0x55e10100f100
array_bytes_ptr: 0x55e10100f100
array_struct_addr%64: 0
array_bytes_addr%64: 0
*/
```

Comment: This will probably not work because it's holding a reference, and it's specifying the alignment of that reference.

Comment: @Fifnmar That's why I provided **two** solutions. One for the alignment of the reference (as in your question, but it is probably not what you want), another one for the alignment of the included bytes.

Comment: The second method works! The trick of including the length first solves the problem. It seems that the compiler is able to align the bytes according to their usage.